# keras model makes very inaccurate predictions

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, deep-learning, neural-network

I never worked with KI before and recently got a task to make a model which can predict two specific rooms in an building and outdoor asap. -.-

For learning and testing I created an dataset with three classes: bedroom, kitchen, outdoor and tried to create a model with it (~14k pictures each).

With my non-existing knowhow I think I already got pretty far but I have a few problems I can't get my head around.

At first the model predicted always the same: the last class got always 100%.
Now I'm pretty sure it was a problem with the model definition and changed it.

Now the model gets a few prediction right, but most of them are still wrong...
And as far as I understand the training and validation accuracy ratio is also pretty bad.

I hope someone can help me and bring me on the right path :D

BTW if you now how to infuse the label names into the model so thats easy to know them when deploying the model on another device is easy, please tell me ;)

[Jupyter Notebook](https://docdro.id/pmqOQ52)

**Current Model**

```
# ----- Define Keras Model -----
model = Sequential([
    layers.Rescaling(1./255, input_shape=(IMAGE_HEIGHT, IMAGE_WIDTH, 3)),
    layers.Conv2D(64, (3, 3), activation = 'relu'),
    layers.MaxPooling2D(2, 2),
    layers.Conv2D(64, (3, 3), activation = 'relu'),
    layers.MaxPooling2D(2, 2),
    layers.Conv2D(64, (3, 3), activation = 'relu'),
    layers.MaxPooling2D(2, 2),
    layers.Flatten(),
    # tf.keras.layers.Dropout(0.2),
    layers.Dense(128, activation = 'relu'),
    layers.Dense(len(class_names), activation = 'softmax')
])
```

[Accuracy of current model](https://i.stack.imgur.com/g6VVZ.png)

Comment: Please never add code as external links, images, or colab, always it should be in the question itself as text.

Comment: I wanted to but its nearly impossible to add the whole jupyter notebook with output in a nice format.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your model looks too lightweight for the task. Try increasing number of convolutional-maxpool blocks from 2 to 5-6, convolutional filters from 32 to 64. Also, increase number of training epochs to 10-20. This should improve accuracy.

Comment: I will try it and write back. I also added Dropout, but is this even needed in my case? I wasn't pretty sure. An is there a way to calculate or get to know which numbers a appropriate?

Comment: In general it's a trial and error approach. If your model is simple and doesn't perform well, it's a good idea to increase complexity and check if it helps. Not sure about dropout, I'd put it before the first Dense layer and set its parameter to 0.2-0.3. 0.5 may be a bit too high.

Comment: With epochs 10 the accuracy is only at 0.7547 with a loss of 0.4632. I increase it to 20.

Comment: I created the model with 20 epochs now and I don't know why but the prediction got worse. Now it again predicts everything as "outdoor".

Comment: Notebook: https://docdro.id/JhjF03y

Comment: You should not increase parameters of maxpool layer, leave them (2,2) as before. Add more convolutional and maxpool layers to the model instead. Also, consider rescaling of input images, multiply them by 1/255, at both training and testing stages. Validation accuracy seems not bad anyway, you may try to check results for other images.

Comment: Again, thanks for your help. How many convolutional and maxpool layers should I add? I don't know on what I should orientate myself. I added the current model to my question, is it like what you meant?

Comment: Yes, the current model looks ok. It has 3 conv+maxpool layers, you can experiment with adding 1-2 more and check if it gives higher validation accuracy after training. The best orientation for you are the results on your validation dataset.

Comment: Okay, I ran the model with 20 epochs again but the accuracy got much worse, I also posted it in the question.

Comment: It's not worse, it has raised from previous 0.7 to 0.85 as far as I can see.

Comment: But it still gets 95% of the predictions wrong. And as far as I understood the validation loss shouldn't go up so much